# How to be sure that Newtons method converge to find the optimal solution for a strictly convex one-variable function?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

I have a function of one variable with a positive domain $(0, \infty)$. This function is strictly convex with any parameters (the second derivative is positive). I want to minimize this function.

In the examples that I have tried, I always found the optimal solution with Newton's method (with a tolerance level being not a problem). However, how can I guarantee that I will always find the optimal solution using this method for this function with different parameters? I have been looking for that answer in some books (e.g. *Nonlinear Programming*, Mordecai Avriel) but didn't find a clear answer. It seems that strict convexity is a necessary condition. But is it sufficient?

I would appreciate an answer with the corresponding book to dive deeper. Moreover, a numerical example would also be appreciated if possible.

Thanks.

Edit 1: As additional information, the function $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$ when $x$ approaches both $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: related? or not really? https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient, since the first (for example) Newton step could take you to the negative numbers, so outside your domain. You may have more subtle problems too, s[ee the wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Failure_of_the_method_to_converge_to_the_root)

Comment: Igor Rivin, please see edit 1. It could result useful to provide a solution